# Limit the number of google recaptcha characters

Tags: magento, recaptcha

I'm currently using google recaptcha, and I feel that it can be a little difficult. It is always two words the user has to type in, and some of the words can be up to 7+ characters.

So is there any way to limit the numbers of google recaptcha characters ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to limit the number of characters of Google ReCaptcha.

If the user can't find a captacha because it's too messy, too long, he can ask for another captcha, and that's how it works. Moreover, reducing the number of character would just reduce the effectiveness of ReCaptcha.

If you really want something easier, you have to look for something else or create your own captcha system.